Decomposition of a function
Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function with compact support on $\mathbb{R}$.
Under which hypotheses on $f$ the functional equation (in the $w$ variable)
$$
w(2t)-w(t)=f(t)
$$
admits at least a solution in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$?
Is this studied somewhere?

We can actually characterise the possible solutions $w$, and although it's not just smooth compactly supported functions like you desired, it's still somewhat close enough in my opinion.
If you only care about the characterisation itself, then you can skip to the end, but otherwise I've preferred to present my train of thought instead of just giving a straightforward answer, just in case it can help someone else with a similar problem.
I'll divide this answer into three parts, separated by horizontal bars:

Looking at the necessary conditions on $f$ for the existence of a candidate $w$ (not necessarily smooth or whatever, just at least continuous at $0$), which is really quick as there's only one, that is $f(0) = 0$;
Showing that this condition is also sufficient for constructing the function $w$, and looking at the necessary properties of $w$ in that case;
Concluding by showing that some of the necessary conditions mentioned are also sufficient, thus closing the loop. This will also provide a counterexample where $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^\infty_c$ but not $w$.

But, again, it's not exactly what you desired because I don't currently see any simple conditions on $f$ which would guarantee $w$ to be compactly supported. Hopefully someone else can one day!

Consider $w$ any function which is continuous at $0$, and $f : t \mapsto w(2t) - w(t)$.
Then it's possible to see that we have the following:
$$\forall t \in \mathbb{R},\quad w(t) - w(0) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n \left(w\left(\frac{t}{2^k}\right) - w\left(\frac{t}{2^{k+1}}\right)\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n f\left(\frac{t}{2^{k+1}}\right)$$
and thus that the quantity
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n f\left(\frac{t}{2^{k+1}}\right)$$
needs to exist and be finite in the first place for all $t$.
In particular, $f(0) = 0$ is necessary, otherwise none of these sums would be finite, especially the one for $t = 0$ for obvious reasons.
Note also the fact that an additive constant on the $w$ side won't change $f$, but that up to said additive constant the function $w$ is uniquely determined by $f$ when it exists!

Conversely, let's show that $f(0) = 0$ is actually also a sufficient condition for the existence of a candidate $w$!
Take a function $f$ which is smooth, compactly supported and such that $f(0) = 0$. Denote by $M_n$ the maximum of $|f^{(n)}|$ where $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$-th derivative of $f$.
Then, we have for all $n \geq 1$ :
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}}\left|\left(f\left(\frac{\cdot}{2^{k+1}}\right)\right)^{(n)}(t)\right| = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}}\left|\frac{1}{\left(2^{k+1}\right)^n}f^{(n)}\left(\frac{t}{2^{k+1}}\right)\right| \leq M_n \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)^{k+1} < +\infty$$
which yields the normal, thus uniform convergence of all the derivatives of $\sum_k f_k$ where $f_k$ stands for $t \mapsto f\left(t/2^{k+1}\right)$.
The uniform convergence of $\sum_k f_k$ itself would have been a bit more troublesome, but thankfully we only need convergence of $\sum_k f_k(t_0)$ at any single point $t_0$ to conclude that $\sum_k f_k$ is a convergent series whose limit $w := \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} f_k$ is smooth and satisfies:
$$\forall n \geq 0,\, \forall t \in \mathbb{R},\quad w^{(n)}(t) = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} f_k^{(n)}(t)$$
and we do have that convergence for $t_0 = 0$ since $f_k(0) = 0$ for all $k \geq 0$ thanks to the assumption $f(0) = 0$.
Note that a consequence of the proof is that the derivatives of $w$ are itself bounded, just like the derivatives of $f$.
Moreover, we have the following:
$$\forall t \in \mathbb{R},\quad w(2t) = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} f\left(\frac{2t}{2^{k+1}}\right) = f(t) + \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} f\left(\frac{t}{2^{k+1}}\right) = f(t) + w(t)$$
Thus, if you let $a > 0$ be such that the support of $f$ is contained in the interval $[-a, a]$, that would give, for $|t| \geq a$:
$$w(2t) - w(t) = f(t) = 0$$
Now, if you define $$W_\pm : x \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto w(\pm2^x)$$ then you get two smooth functions which are $1$-periodic for $x \geq \log_2(a)$ thanks to the above property, and such that:
$$\forall t \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\},\quad w(t) = W_{\operatorname{sign}(t)}(\log_2|t|)$$
Hence, if we call $V_\pm$ the $1$-periodic function on $\mathbb{R}$ induced by the $x \geq \log_2(a)$ part of $W_\pm$, there exist two smooth cut-off functions $\chi_\pm$ such that $\chi_-(t) = 0$ if $t \geq -a$ and $\chi_-(t) = 1$ for $t \leq -2a$, $\chi_+(t) = 0$ if $t \leq a$ and $\chi_+(t) = 1$ for $t \geq 2a$, and:
$$w - \left(\chi_- \cdot (V_- \circ \log_2|\cdot|) + \chi_+ \cdot (V_+ \circ \log_2 |\cdot|)\right) \in \mathcal{C}^\infty_c$$
You can define these cut-off functions using mollifiers, I won't do it here because it's more technical than it is interesting...

Consider any function of the form
$$w := \chi_- \cdot (V_- \circ \log_2|\cdot|) + \chi_+ \cdot (V_+ \circ \log_2 |\cdot|) + g + C$$
where $C \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant, $g$ is $\mathcal{C}^\infty_c$ and supported in an interval $[-a, a]$ with $a > 0$, the $V_\pm$s are $1$-periodic functions and the $\chi_\pm$ are cut-off functions such that $\chi_-(t) = 0$ if $t \geq -a$ and $\chi_-(t) = 1$ for $t \leq -2a$, $\chi_+(t) = 0$ if $t \leq a$ and $\chi_+(t) = 1$ for $t \geq 2a$.
Define $f : t \mapsto w(2t) - w(t)$.
Then $f$ is smooth as a sum of smooth functions, $f(0) = 0$, and $f$ is compactly supported as:
$$\forall |t| \geq 2a,\quad f(t) = V_{\operatorname{sign}(2t)}(\log_2|2t|) - V_{\operatorname{sign}(t)}(\log_2|t|) + C - C = 0$$
and we are done.
Looking at what's been proven, we can see that we actually obtained two characterisations:

If $f(0) = 0$, $f$ is smooth and all the derivatives of $f$ are bounded, then
$$w : t \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n f\left(\frac{t}{2^{k+1}}\right)$$
is well-defined, is smooth with all its derivatives being bounded, and satisfies:
$$w(2t) - w(t) = f(t)$$
Conversely, if a function $w$ is smooth and has all its derivatives be bounded, then the function $f : t \mapsto w(2t) - w(t)$ is smooth, satisfies $f(0) = 0$ and has all its derivatives be bounded.

and:

If $f(0) = 0$, $f$ is smooth and compactly supported, then
$$w : t \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n f\left(\frac{t}{2^{k+1}}\right)$$
is well-defined, is smooth, satisfies:
$$w(2t) - w(t) = f(t)$$
and is of the form $$w = \chi_- \cdot (V_- \circ \log_2|\cdot|) + \chi_+ \cdot (V_+ \circ \log_2 |\cdot|) + g$$
where $g$ is smooth and compactly supported in an interval $[-a, a]$ with $a > 0$, the $V_\pm$s are $1$-periodic functions and the $\chi_\pm$ are cut-off functions such that $\chi_-(t) = 0$ if $t \geq -a$ and $\chi_-(t) = 1$ for $t \leq -2a$, $\chi_+(t) = 0$ if $t \leq a$ and $\chi_+(t) = 1$ for $t \geq 2a$.
Conversely, if a function $w$ is smooth and of the form $$w = \chi_- \cdot (V_- \circ \log_2|\cdot|) + \chi_+ \cdot (V_+ \circ \log_2 |\cdot|) + g + C$$
with the same notations and $C$ an additive constant, then the function $f : t \mapsto w(2t) - w(t)$ is smooth, satisfies $f(0) = 0$ and is compactly supported.

A counterexample where $f$ is smooth compactly supported but $w$ isn't then comes naturally by taking your favourite nonzero $1$-periodic function as $V_+$, your favourite $\chi_+$, and then setting $V_-$ and $g$ to $0$.

This answer is a bit on the long side, so feel free to point out any mistake you identify or any doubt you have as I'm sure I probably missed something somewhere!
